# How to transfer files between OSX and Android phone wireless?

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, android, file-transfer, osx-yosemite

I have MacBook running OSX 10.10.1 and Android 4.4 phone (Sony Z3 Compact). Both devices are connected thru Wi-Fi to the same router.

Is there any way to easily transfer files wireless between them? I've tried to use bluetooth, but it is possible to transfer some files only (for ex., `mp3` could be transferred, but `lrc` can not). I use dropbox now, but it is time consuming.

Both devices shouldn't loose internet connection (or connection to the router) during file transfer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might benefit from Droid NAS (Google Play Store) - or one of the many equivalents. Basically Droid NAS allows you to transfer folders of a WiFi network.

Answer (score 0):

**[The fastest way to transfer files between Mac and Android](http://www.androidbeat.com/2014/04/fastest-way-transfer-files-mac-android/)**
Which is about DroidNAS which was said above. Also you can take advantage of others too.
You can use [Filedrop](http://www.howtogeek.com/201381/how-to-transfer-files-over-wi-fi-between-your-pc-tablet-or-phone/) and also you can use airdrop for [mac](http://www.wikihow.com/Share-Files-With-Airdrop-on-a-Mac) and [android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.airdropfull&hl=en) .

Answer (score -1):

A good wireless method that I use between Android and Mac is Soduto with KdeConnect.

Both are open source apps.

You can find Soduto for Mac here https://soduto.com/

You can find KDEConnect for Android here https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kde.kdeconnect_tp&hl=en_IN&gl=US

Now install these and make sure they are on the same Wifi network. Then Pair the two devices (using Soduto on mac to pair with Android through KDEConnect).

Pairing is necessary only once, and you can transfer files and even your Clipboard history across the two devices anytime you want without the hassle of connecting wires!!